# How to compute mean() for particular column in Pandas DataFrame without considering NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From my understanding, axis=0 is running vertically downwards across rows and axis =1 is running horizontally across columns
for example:

```
In [55]: df1
    Out[55]:
       x  y  z
    0  1  3  8
    1  2  4  NaN
    2  3  5  7
    3  4  6  NaN
    4  5  7  6
    5 NaN 1  9
    6 NaN 9  5
```

so mean across column df.mean(axis=0) gives:

```
    x  3
    y  5
    z  7
```

But if I want to drop missing values by column as

```
   y
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7
5  1
6  9
```

then I have to use df.dropna(axis=1) rather than df.dropna(axis=0) to get the output I want, but isn't axis=1 regarding rows, how come it mean columns in this case?

Comment: Your title is miss-leading. This is panda specific.

Answer (score 0):

from the pandas documentation:

```
DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
"Return object with labels on given axis omitted where alternately
any or all of the data are missing"

Parameters: 
    axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, or tuple/list thereof
    Pass tuple or list to drop on multiple axes
```

So the function is defined in a way that `axis=1` means columns. 
If you want to drop by row you just call it like this:

```
df_dropped = df.dropna(how='all') # drop by row
```

Comment: but isn't it inconstitent? axis=1 means rows in most of situatins but column in some cases?

Comment: At first glance I would say yes, it is inconsistent. But maybe there was some other thought behind the design of the function... I haven't worked with pandas that much tbh. So I don't feel qualified to say something like that

Answer (score 0):

`dropna()` drops the **labels** on the given axis so `df.dropna(axis=1)` means "look at the labels across axis 1 (i.e. x, y, and z) and drop that label if there are any NaN in that column"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way you can calculate the mean without dropping NaN's but still don't consider them in the mean.

**1. Hard Way**

```
val = df['y']
val[~val.isnull()].mean()
```

**2. Easy Way**

```
df['y'].mean()
```

DataFrame.mean() function implicitly excludes 'NaN' values from the computation. You don't need to handle it explicitly. It does so using the argument `skipna` whose default value is `skina=True`.

If you explicitly want full length of column to be considered, irregardless of presence of NaN values, you can use set `skipna=False` as below:

```
df['y'].mean(skipna=False)
```

Its always a good habit to refer official documentation.
[Refer docs for `DataFrame.mean()` here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html?highlight=mean#pandas.DataFrame.mean)

Cheers!